# Changing object property in an array with React Hooks does not evoke a re-render

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

When I change the property of an object in an array with react hooks, the component does not re-render.

I consulted my lead tech and he explained that React searches "breadth" over "depth," meaning React sees the object, but it can't see changes to the object's properties.

```
const [array, setArray] = useState([
        {'id': 0, text: '0'},
        {'id': 1, text: '1'},
        {'id': 2, text: '2'}
    ]);
```

I expect this the component to re-render when the state is changed, but the behavior acts as if the array of objects were not changed at all.

If I create a copy of array as newArray and change newArray[2].text = '3' and setArray(newArray), react thinks the array hasn't changed. Thus, the component does not reload.

As a workaround, I use

```
const [trigger, setTrigger] = useState(false);
setTrigger(!trigger);
```

to force reload. However, this is a hacky way to reload the component and I want a more React way of doing it.

Thank you advance!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What your lead tech meant by "breath over depth" is right.

React monitors only the "reference" changes. When you change a property of an object, the reference is the same.

Think of it as when you do, you can still change `a.value` even though it's declared constant.

```
const a = {value: 'abc'}
a.value = 'xxx'
console.log(a.value) // prints 'xxx'
```

But you can't do

```
const a = {value: 'abc'}
a = {something: 'bad'}
 not allowed.
```

The same applies to an array of objects (or a plain old array).
It's a reference type, thus changing the property of an array element would not change the reference of `newArray`.

```
newArray[2].text = '3' and setArray(newArray)
```

`newArray` still points to the same address space.

So when you create an entire new array using a spread syntax or `Array.from`, you create an entire new reference (a copy) and, set a new value, and lastly set the state.

```
const [array, setArray] = useState([
        {'id': 0, text: '0'},
        {'id': 1, text: '1'},
        {'id': 2, text: '2'}
    ]);

// ... somewhere else.
const copy = [...array, {'id': 2, ]
// or -> const copy = Array.from(array)
copy[2].text = '3' 
setArray(copy)
```

The code above creates a new `copy` of `array` state. Setting that copy with updated value will trigger the re-render. (but beware, it creates a "shallow copy", not a "deep copy")

Since your data structure is complex, you might as well use [ImmerJS](https://github.com/immerjs/immer), which lets you change the reference as if you are writing current code.

Answer (score 3):

I think the problem is in how you are copying the array. Arrays in js are `reference type` so you can't just do this:

```
const arr = [1,2,4]
const copy = arr
```

Cause you are just changing the pointer not the reference itself. Try this:

```
const copy = [...arr]
```

Now you are creating a new array with the `spread` of every `arr` elements. To do that using `useState`

```
const Comp = () =>{
    const [arr, setArr] = useState([1,2,3,4])

    return <button onClick={() => setArr([...arr, 5])}>Change</button>
}
```